# For $|x|\leq 1,$ show that $|e^x-1-\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}|<\frac{1}{8}$

Tags: calculus

For $|x|\leq 1,$ show that $|e^x-1-\dfrac{x^2}{2!}-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}|<\dfrac{1}{8}$

I've tried substituting x=1 in as that should give me the maximum value of the LHS, but the number I get isn't <1/8! I didn't think the question would be that easy, so how am I meant to do it?

The question is the chapter about Maclaurin series in my textbook, but I can't find the link to Maclaurin series this question has...

edit: this seems to be a typo in the book

Comment: There is a missing $-x$ term.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I have typed out the question exactly as the question shows - is this a typo then?

Comment: $$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+...\\|e^x-1-\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}|=\\|x-\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^5}{5!}...|=$$

Comment: Almost certainly. The inequality, as you observed, does not hold. The natural expression is $e^x-1-x-x^2/2!-x^3/3!$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=e^x$ then using the estimates for the remainder of the [Taylor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Estimates_for_the_remainder): we have

$$|f^{(4)}(x)|\le M=e\;\forall x\in[-1,1]$$
so

$$|e^x-1-\dfrac{x^2}{2!}-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}|\le M\frac1{4!}=\frac e{24}<\frac3{24}=\frac18$$

Comment: but:  where is x in expansion ?